# Cancel a delay if same observable emits

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

```js
const observable = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(0);

observable.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

rxjs
  .of(1)
  .pipe(rxjs.operators.delay(500))
  .subscribe(v => observable.next(v));
  
observable.next(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the observable above emits 3 values in order : 0, 2, 1.

Would it be possible to cancel (or ignore) the value "1" when the value "2" is emitted ? (Without closing the subscription)

Comment: There are better ways to emit numbers one after another, rxjs timer for example.
in any case, if you have an observable with subscription and want that new value that emited will cancel the last subscription and switch to a new one read about switchMap. But i'm not sure if it's possible in this code that you added above

Comment: @Lagistos this is a [mcve]. I used numbers to be quick. In reality, the `next`s are called on mouse events. I would like to cancel the delayed `mouseenter` on `mouseleave`, because otherwise, the leave emits, then the enter does too.

Comment: Based on what condition you want to ignore the last value? You could use `ignoreElements()` before `delay` if you never want to receive the value from `of`. Or you can also use `EMPTY` as your source Observable.

Comment: There's no condition, I would like to cancel a delayed emition if a new emition comes up. I know that you can use SwitchMap for that, but I don't know how to use it for a single observable.

Comment: @trichetriche i fixed my answer now that i know the purpuse of this, you are looking for debounceTime wrote you a new answer below

Comment: use `debounceTime(500)` instead of `delay(500)`. @trichetriche

Comment: Your question is unclear, you have 2 subscription to different Observables in your example, and ask your question as if there was only a single observable with a single subscription. @trichetriche

Comment: @n00dl3 I have a subscription to a single observable. The second one is a subscription to `of`, which can just be replaced by a timeout. I thought I would use `of` to keep the RxJS context. But in the end, there's a single observable I have subscribed to that interests me.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you need to `switchMap` from your source and apply a `delay` inside of it.

```
switchMap(value =>
 of(value).pipe(delay(50))
)
```

An illustration and a **[playground for switchMap with a delay](https://thinkrx.io/gist/4d14270613c5bdb8a60ac414945b29f2)**:

[image: delay with a switchMap]

And heres a snippet:

```js
const {Subject, of} = rxjs;
const {switchMap, delay} = rxjs.operators;

const subject = new Subject(0);

subject
  .pipe(
     switchMap(value =>
       // switchMap to a delayed value
       of(value).pipe(delay(500))
     )
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));

// immediately emit 0
subject.next(0);

// emit 1 in 1 sec
setTimeout(()=>{
  subject.next(1);
}, 1000)

// emit 2 in 1.2 sec
setTimeout(()=>{
  subject.next(2);
}, 1200)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Heres an example with mousehover

```js
const {fromEvent, merge, of, EMPTY} = rxjs;
const {switchMap, delay, mapTo} = rxjs.operators;

const button = document.getElementById('pane');
const mouseOver$ = fromEvent(button, 'mouseover').pipe(
  mapTo(true)
);

const mouseOut$ = fromEvent(button, 'mouseout').pipe(
  mapTo(false)
);

merge(mouseOver$, mouseOut$)
  .pipe(
     switchMap(value => {
       if (!value) { return EMPTY; }
       return of('mouse is over').pipe(delay(500))
     })
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>

<style>
#pane{
  margin: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}</style>

<div id="pane"><div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried switchMap but it didn't work. The strange part is, I then tried a sub-subscription (putting a `subscribe` into the callback of another `subscribe`), and it worked ...

Comment: @trichetriche, having a sub-subscribe would be a bad practice. Probably theres some minor thing missing in your approach. Could you share this code part?

Comment: totally agreed. That's why I have just abandoned this idea and went on something entirely different that took me like 2 minutes ... And hence, why I can't share the code with you. I'm going to delete my question anyway, but thank you for your input ! EDIT : can't delete the question ...

Comment: @trichetriche, I've added a snippet with mouseover. Might be helpful for further implementations. GL :)

Comment: @trichetriche, "can't delete the question" -- it might've been due to me editing the answer. So check out my update and try again ;)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, even 2.5 years later you helped me :)

Answer (score 4):

The operator you are looking for is `debounceTime` :

> ### `debounceTime`
>
> Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission.

[source](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime)

```js
rxjs.interval(100)
  .pipe(
    rxjs.operators.take(10),
    rxjs.operators.debounceTime(500)
  )
  .subscribe((v)=>{
    console.log(v);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: As stated in the other answer, it doesn't work for me, because I am using mouse events : using this operator increases the time waiting for the animation to happen.

Answer (score 1):

So for mouse enter and leave you are looking for debounceTime for example:

```
const observable = new BehaviorSubject(0);
observable
  .pipe(debounceTime(500))
 .subscribe(console.log);

observable.next(1),
observable.next(2);
setTimeout(() => observable.next(3) , 1000)
```

In this example that will print 2 and after one seconed 3.
After each emitited value the observable wait for 500 ms and if there are no new value it will print in the subscribe else it will cancel the last one and start this proccess again, hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This doesn't do what I ask, it doesn't cancel the previous values, it just waits 500ms before emitting the next value

Comment: It's cancel, you can see that it's not printing 0 and 1.
i add stackblitz link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cveugz?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you for that, I'm going to try this tommorow !

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work : the issue is that the emitions aren't linear like your exemple. Since it's bound to a mouse event, it just react instantly. In your case, the operator adds a delay on every event, making it very not user-friendly.

Comment: Can you explaine the exact feature you are trying to create, you said that is something with mouse enter and leave but what about them?, this will help me to give you an idea how to solve this

Comment: I am creating a menu that can be expanded on mouse enter. Every item of that menu can then display a submenu as a popover. If the menu is not fully opened (500ms to open), the submenu should not pop up. Right now, the issue is that if the user enters the menu then leaves it instantly, it emits a false value, then a true value (because of the delay), making the submenu pop after the menu is  closed.