# Angular - improve my autocomplete with switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, autocomplete, switchmap

At the moment I have the following setup :

In my component :

```
/**/
onCitySearch() {
    this.citiesService.getCities(this.citySearchControl.value);
}
```

In my service :

```
    /**/
    getCities(term: string) {
        if (term.length < 3 || term === this.lastSearchTerm || this.autocompleteAjaxLock) {
        return;
    }

    this.autocompleteAjaxLock = true;
    this.httpClient
        .get<City[]>(environment.api_url + '/api/city/autocomplete?term=' + term)
        .subscribe(
            (cities) => {
                this.lastSearchTerm = term;
                this.cities = cities;
                this.citiesUpdated.next([...this.cities]);
                this.autocompleteAjaxLock = false;
            },
            error => this.autocompleteAjaxLock = false
        );
}
```

My component is subscribed to the service cities and automatically gets notified when the search is updated.
Now, with the lock system I setup, if the user types quickly my search doesnt get updated.
I read around about switchMap, that should be appropriate for my use case.
Where and how should I implement it ? In my component or in the service function ?

Comment: Have a look at this example https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#practical-observable-usage

Answer (score 1):

Why is the autoCompleteAjax lock? Are you "afraid" of too many Http requests? Just make sure you store the subscriptions created with the this.httpClient.get(...) invocation. Then upon every subsequent call to getCities loop through the cache of subscriptions and unsubscribe them (this will cancel the Http request and/or response).

As an alternative (addition) you might want to implement a short delay upfront (before invoking getCities) and when the next key stroke comes in the queued requests have to be cancelled (which will not even reach the GetCities method). This can be done very nicely with the well praised RxJs library (that comes alongside with every modern Angular application setup).

Have a look at this [Cancel a delay if same observable emits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851474/cancel-a-delay-if-same-observable-emits) for examples of RxJs `switchMap` and `debounceTime` method/operator.

Answer (score 1):

A few general things:

1. You're right that **switchMap** would be a good choice as it has a cancelling effect on previous emissions.
2. It's always good to introduce a delay with typed user input in the form of **debounceTime**.
3. Try to get out of the habit of assigning variables outside of your stream with **tap** or **subscribe**, especially when there is likely a way to assign a variable directly, such as with an **async** pipe.

Instead of **switchMap**, the solution below uses **switchScan** to maintain a typeahead state.

- First the user input is debounced.
- It is then cleansed with **map** so only relevant data is returned.
- **distinctUntilChanged** is used to prevent repeats of cleansed results.
- It is then filtered so that it is at least 3 characters long.
- Now the magic happens with **switchScan**:
- The second parameter sets the initial state.
- If the *currentTerm* exists in *terms* then the exiting *terms* and new *currentTerm* are returned as part of a new state.
- Otherwise, the term is searched for with the api call, added to *terms* and a new state with *currentTerm* is returned with the updated *terms*.
- Finally, the result is transformed with **map** as just an array of terms corresponding to *currentTerm*.

```
interface TypeaheadState = {
  terms: { [term: string]: City[] };
  currentTerm: string;
}
readonly searchTermSubject = new Subject<string>();

readonly typeAhead$ = searchTermSubject.pipe(
  debounceTime(100), 
  map(x => x.trim().toLowerCase()),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  filter(x => x.length >= 3),
  switchScan((state, currentTerm) =>
      state[currentTerm] 
        ? of({ currentTerm, terms: state.terms })
        : this.httpClient
          .get<City[]>(environment.api_url + '/api/city/autocomplete?term=' + term)
          .pipe(map(res => ({ currentTerm, terms: { ...state.terms, [currentTerm]: res }))),
      { currentTerm: '', terms: { '': [] } } as TypeaheadState 
    )
  ),
  map(state => state.terms[state.currentTerm])
);
```

If **switchMap** was used then the state would've had to exist outside of the operator.  By using a *x-scan* operator you're able to keep everything local to the oeprator, resulting in a cleaner solution. The **switchScan** documentation is scant, so check the **[mergeScan](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeScan)** documentation instead, as it is pretty much the same except for the switching effect.